# Extension of Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

php has .php extension 
asp has .asp 
asp.net has aspx 
html has .html 
xml has .xml
every language has its extension, then what is the extension for Ruby On Rails language?

Comment: there's no "ruby on rails" language.

Comment: If there where such extension it would probably be .ror

Comment: Ruby on Rails is a framework made on top of Ruby language. Its not a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

First google, by the way Ruby is language and it has **.rb** extension and for rails is framework on top of ruby.

Comment: google provided this answer when I search, so sometimes people must insert first answer to find on google for the next user have the same inquiry.